# How do I find the equation of this plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the equation of the plane that contains the points (1,1,-1) and (2,1,1) and the distance between this plane and the line r: X = (1, 0, 2) + λ(1, 0, 2) is 1.

Answer (score 0):

The line $r$ goes threw the origin (for $\lambda=-1$). Draw (find the equation) of the sphere of center $O$, of radius $1$. Find the equation of the plane tangent to this sphere at point $P(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, and determine $x_0$, $y_0$ and $z_0$ such that this plane contains $A(1,1,-1)$ and $B(2,1,1)$.

I think you should find two planes.